# Active state not being set by smooth-scroll plugin (JS modification)

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, smooth-scrolling

I'm having some trouble with a script which takes care of smooth scrolling as well as the active state on my main navigation. Plugin: http://tinyurl.com/amz4kob

Please note that the navigation bar is fixed so effectively has no height.

I've got two issues which I can't seem to overcome:

1. On page load the active state is applied to the contact link. If you scroll down 1px the active state is correctly applied to the home link.
2. I can't for the life of me figure out how to modify the script to pay attention to anchors within an element with a certain ID? i.e. I only want this script to apply the active state to the elements within the  tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

@rrfive

To make life easy here is the commented script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Get Sections top position
function getTargetTop(elem){

    //gets the id of the section header
    //from the navigation's href e.g. ("#html")
    var id = elem.attr("href");

    //Height of the navigation
    var offset = 0;

    //Gets the distance from the top and subtracts the height of the nav.
    return $(id).offset().top - offset;
}

//Smooth scroll when user click link that starts with #
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {

    //gets the distance from the top of the section refenced in the href.
    var target = getTargetTop($(this));

    //scrolls to that section.
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 500);

    //prevent the browser from jumping down to section.
    event.preventDefault();
});

//Pulling sections from main nav.
var sections = $('a[href^="#"]');

// Go through each section to see if it's at the top.
// if it is add an active class
function checkSectionSelected(scrolledTo){
    //How close the top has to be to the section.
    var threshold = 54;

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

        //get next nav item
        var section = $(sections[i]);

        //get the distance from top
        var target = getTargetTop(section);

        //Check if section is at the top of the page.
        if (scrolledTo > target - threshold && scrolledTo < target + threshold) {
            sections.removeClass("active");
            section.addClass("active");
        }
    };
}

//Check if page is already scrolled to a section.
checkSectionSelected($(window).scrollTop());

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    checkSectionSelected($(window).scrollTop())
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you're using checks the position of the `<div class="section"></div>` elements on the page, but because you've made them `display:none;`, all the sections are returning "0 pixels" from the top of the page, and since the "CONTACT" section is the last on the page, it's stopping there.

So, simply remove `display:none;` from `.section` in your CSS and it'll work fine.

```
.section {
    /*display: none; <-- Comment this line out. */
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 990px;
}
```

Comment: Golly, that's so easy it's embarrassing. Thanks Coby, your input is very much appreciated.